# Can all deterministic non-oblivious Turing machines be simulated by oblivious ones?

Tags: turing-machines

According to [Relations Among Complexity Measures](https://learn.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/pluginfile.php/69375/mod_resource/content/1/Relations-Among-Complexity-Measures--contains-Oblivious-TM_Pippenger_Fischer.pdf) by Pippenger & Fischer, the definition of an oblivious machine is:

> An oblivious machine is one whose head movements are fixed functions of time, independent of the inputs to the machine.

In other words, a Turing machine $M$ is oblivious if and only if it exists a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{k}$ and the location of each $M$'s heads can be determined by $f(n)$ with $n$ the number of steps run by the machine $M$ and $k$ the number of tapes.

In the abstract of the paper mentioned above, it is said:

> Any machine with one-dimensional tapes can be simulated on-line by an oblivious machine with two one-dimensional tapes.

Now, let's imagine a non-oblivious Turing machine $M_{no}$ that can either accepts or rejects any input $x$. For instance:

- if $x=00$, $M_{no}$ accepts the input after 10 steps;
- if $x=01$, $M_{no}$ rejects the input after 12 steps;
- if $x=10$, $M_{no}$ accepts the input after 8 steps;
- if $x=11$, $M_{no}$ rejects the input after 7 steps.

According to Pippenger & Fischer, there is an oblivious Turing machine $M_o$ that can simulates $M_{no}$. As $M_{no}$ always halt, I could imagine an oblivious Turing machine that simulates it following the algorithm described by Pippenger & Fischer and halting after $n_{worst}$ steps which is the worst number of steps for any input of size $n$. In the example I gave, it is 12 for an input of size 2.

First question: is it possible to determine $n_{worst}$ in advance for every Turing machine?

But, what about another non-oblivious Turing machine $M_{inifnite\_no}$ which behaves exactly as $M_{no}$ except it never halts when the input is $x = 11$? In this case, $2_{worst}=+\infty$ and the oblivious machine simulating $M_{inifnite\_no}$ would never halts for any input of size 2 which is not the behavior of $M_{inifnite\_no}$. Therefore, this machine doesn't exist.

Second question: Is the theorem of Pippenger & Fischer only true for Turing machine that can halt?

Comment: If it can help, I designed a non-oblivious TM that can either accepts, rejects or never halts with different inputs of the same size: http://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/kdofikmqot I don't see how it is possible to simulate it with an oblivious TM.

Comment: The construction by Pippenger & Fischer gives an oblivious TM that runs in O(n log n), not n (where n is your n_worst). 1. Determine n_worst in advance simply by executing the TM in question on all inputs of the length in question (in a mathematical sense, this may not always concretely be found). 2. The correct corresponding oblivious TM that does not halt on some input of length n is the TM that fails to halt on any input of length n. It can exist, but of course it doesn't accept the same language in general.